# Which username 'etckeeper' uses to push?

Tags: linux, git, version, rhel7

Just want to know which username (or under which user) `etckeeper` using fo`r git push`.

I've setup a alerting system to MS Teams for each pus, but it gives my username while pushing even the push is done by `root` user.

Comment: You might be confusing bash user and git user. Check `user.name` in your `.gitconfig` That being said, it's extremely difficult to answer such a question. You're welcome here but you'll see that questions are much more attracting to helpers when the asker is putting some minimal effort in substance and language.

Answer (score 0):

[`etckeeper`](https://etckeeper.branchable.com/) can indeed [push automatically to a remote Git repository](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Etckeeper#Automatic_push_to_remote_repo).

The commits pushed can have their own associated `user.name` / `user.email`: check `/etc/.git/config` and see if said commits are done with your username.

If that is the case, even though the push are done by root, the commits would still retain their authorship.